# How do I start ntop with super-user privileges?

Tags: services

I have installed ntop on my machine and I need to specify which network interface it should listen on. When I go to **Admin -> Configure -> Startup Options** in the web interface it says:

> You cannot set the capture interface:
>   missing privileges.
>
> You need to start
>   ntop with super-user privileges [-u]

How do I add the -u to the service startup?

Comment: It's generally a poor idea to run services as root. Do you know if ntop drops its superuser privileges after startup?

Answer (score 1):

There's page on this in the Ubuntu community docs: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ntop

It says:

> When first installing & configuring
>   the ntop application you need to set
>   an admin password.
>
> ```
> sudo ntop --set-admin-password
> ```

Comment: I did that when I installed ntop. That sets the website admin login password.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. It may be that that setting can't be changed through the Web interface. I just tried it on my machine, and I could switch the interface by specifying it at startup:

sudo ntop -u ntop -d -i ethX

Answer (score 0):

The user is defined at /var/lib/ntop/init.cfg, I am not sure it's safe to change it since it was packaged to run with ntop, it was expected to work.

Comment: Right now it has USER="ntop". If I change this value to anything else it errors saying it cannot run as that user.